# Runtime float calculation vs evaluated calculation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

My question is not about the fine points of floating-point calculations, but about the differences in how it's evaluated.  Given this:

```
float a = 1f / 12;
int b = (int)(1f / a);
```

At runtime, b will be 12.  But if I evaluate its expression in something like QuickWatch or LINQPad, it's 11.  In fact, I'm unable to recreate the result of 11 at runtime using `float`, `double`, or `decimal`; truncation or `Math.Floor`.

What's behind the difference between dynamic evaluation of the expression and the evaluation at runtime?

**EDIT**:

Since I'm seeing comments about people getting a result different from mine, here is what I'm seeing.

The result at runtime:

[image: Runtime result]

The result when evaluated by VS QuickWatch:

[image: Eval result]

The result in LINQPad:

[image: LINQPad result]

My VS and framework versions:

[image: VS and framework versions]

Comment: QuickWatch being the QuickWatch of Visual Studio? Because my VS2019 QuickWatch calcs correctly 12, if I paste `(int)(1f / a)`

Comment: LINQPad version 6.11.11 (X64) says the result is 12

Comment: @xanatos That is indeed interesting. I just tried it myself and reproducibly get 11 (with two separate entries in Quickwatch). How did you make your entries?

Comment: Which version of .NET Core / Framework are you running? 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: The short answer is that float results are not consistent across runtimes and bitness.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating-point math consistent in C#? Can it be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683059/is-floating-point-math-consistent-in-c-can-it-be)

Comment: Probably a bug in the quickwatch of Visual Studio... Your error is reproducible, but in the same quickwatch `(int)(float)(1f / a)` is correct. I'm not sure how the quickwatch is executed and if it really does C# code or it emulates it in some way

Comment: related and possible duplicates: [Floating point inconsistency between expression and assigned object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13290758/995714), [Why does this double arithmetic give two different answers on a single machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48784911/995714), [C# - Inconsistent math operation result on 32-bit and 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2461319/995714), [Strange compiler behavior with float literals vs float variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3088372/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a matter of floating point calculations

> Program with 32Bit ( Any CPU -> prefer 32Bit checked )

[image]

> Program with 64Bit

[image]

> Visual Studio is wrapped in 32-bit, so I think that's because QuickWatch runs in 32-bit.

> This is like calculating (int)(1f/12) in QuickWatch

[image]

> So I think it would be better to check what was calculated

[image]